# How do i host classic asp files within MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp-classic

Is it possible to render classic asp files from within my MVC application?

I have an application which lives at

```
http://localhost/myMVCapp/
```

and i put the asp files within a subfolder off the application root

i.e.

```
http://localhost/mymvcapp/asp/news.asp
```

I keep getting 500 errors if i try and request the file.

I believe i need to supply a web.config within this folder which allows the request through but i am unable to workout the correct settings.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can Convert your folder to [web application](http://www.affiliatewiz.com/support/appstartpoint.asp) and then you should write your own [Route](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/12/15/redirect-routes-and-other-fun-with-routing-and-lambdas.aspx).